# Шифр Цезаря с ключевым словом

Tags: python, шифрование

Реализовал вроде правильно,ввод слова и отступа,всё учёл,но ругается на функцию remove ,не знаю почему
for symbol in string:
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable ,в чём причина?

```
from random import *

cryptMode = input("[E]ncrypt|[D]ecrypt:").upper()
if cryptMode not in ['E', 'D']:
    print("Error:"); raise SystemExit
Alphalist = list("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")
startMessage = input('Write:').upper()
numberkey = int(input('Отступ: '))
key = list(input('Write: ').upper())


def remove(alpha, string):
    for symbol in string:
        if symbol not in [chr(x) for x in range(65, 91)] \
        or string.count(symbol) > 1: string.remove(symbol)
        if symbol in alpha: alpha.remove(symbol)
    return alpha, string


def insert(alpha_string):
    for index, symbol in enumerate(alpha_string[1]):
        alpha_string[0].insert((numberkey + index) % 26, symbol)
    return alpha_string[0]


def encryptDecrypt(mode, message, key, final=""):
    alpha = insert(remove(Alphalist, key))
    for symbol in message:
        if mode == 'E':
            final += alpha[(alpha.index(symbol) + key) % 26]
        else:
            final += alpha[(alpha.index(symbol) - key) % 26]
    return final


message = encryptDecrypt(cryptMode, startMessage, numberkey)
print("Final", message)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for index, symbol in enumerate(alpha_string[1]):
```

`alpha_string[1]` у вас похоже является числом

А вообще у вас код очень уж усложнен

Я бы сделал такой код:

```
text = "ATest"
shift = 3

table = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"

result = ''.join(table[(table.index(i) + shift) % len(table)] for i in text.upper())

print(result)
```

шифровка или расшифровка - это всего лишь положительный или отрицательный `shift`

Comment: А как можно сделать легче?

Comment: @Андреас Вавилин, для начала скажите какой у вас словарь - [А-Z], а как поступать с цифрами и русским алфавитом?

Comment: я ввожу слово в допустимом мне алфавите A-Z

Comment: добавил в свой ответ код

Comment: Да это просто шифр цезаря а реализация с ключевым словом сложнее

Comment: а вам нужно шифрование с блокнотами? т.е. шифр Виженера?

Comment: Шифр цезаря с ключевым словом,означает,что после отступа пишется какое-то ключевое слово без потворений букв в этом алфавите,и уже потом шифруется